# Regex to match first part of string (up to the first occurrence of a space character) if it doesn't contain the sequence ;host=

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I have this string `cpu.usage_system;cpu=cpu-total;host=host1 6.94024205748818 1626401140`(graphite metric message with tag support).

I'm trying to match the first part of the string, up to the first occurrence of a space character... but only if that first part of the string doesn't contain `;host=`.

I can match all characters up to the first occurrence of a space with `^([\S]+)`.
I have the feeling I should be using a negative lookahead to check for the absence of `;host=` but I can't figure out how to put it all together.

The idea is to match the first part of the metric label (& tags), see if contains a host tag, if it does contain a host tag... leave it alone. If it doesn't contain a host tag, append one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, depending on what else you need the regex to do, but if you just want to exclude matching lines that contain `;host=`, this lookahead should work:

`^(?!.*;host=)([\S]+)`